# Test-CsExStorageConnectivity Results in Error: "The Request Failed With An Empty Response"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016, skype-for-business-2016

I am attempting to integrate a Skype for Business Server 2015 (*running on Windows Server 2016*) with an Exchange Server 2016 (*running on Windows Server 2012 R2*).  I was following the guide [here](http://blog.schertz.name/2015/09/exchange-and-skype-for-business-integration/) and have been successful in creating the partner applications on both servers.  However, when I attempt to test the setup, it fails with the error below:

**Which results in the following error:**

```
Test-CsExStorageConnectivity : ExCreateItem exchange operation failed, code=574, 
reason=#CTX#{ctx:{traceId:192143289, activityId:"fa709643-3903-49a3-af3e-c8dcff288259"}}
#CTX#StoreException: code=ErrorUnhandledException, reason=Wrapped callback failed ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of '', but expected 
'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
```

**Here's the command I issued on the SfB Server:**

```
Test-CsExStorageConnectivity -SipUri "sip:First.Lastname@mydomain.com" -Verbose
```

Looks like another user experienced a similar issue on [this TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/abf064fb-d72f-41cb-8631-a53414879240/sfb-integration-with-exchange-2016-fails-client-found-response-content-type-of-texthtml-but?forum=sfbfr), but his resolution had to do with a Kemp Load Balancer - which I'm not using.  Has anyone run into this problem before and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind folks.

I managed to resolve my issue by resetting the EWS Virtual Directory from the Exchange Control Panel.

You see, the whole time I'd been getting the test failure, I was able to browse manually to the EWS at https://EXCH_FQDN/ews/exchange.asmx from the SKYPE server; it just prompted me for credentials.  So I figured there was something wrong with the authentication setup on the EWS and since the test cmdlet didn't ask for credentials, it was likely failing somehow.  I tinkered with various combinations of the authentication settings manually, but none seemed to work.  So I finally decided to just reset them to default.

This seems to have cleared out whatever the issue was and I was able to run the test cmdlet successfully.